# what is preg expression for this date format

Tags: php, regex

I want to get only date from string in PHP. What is preg expression for this date format:

```
24/11/2013
```

I have additional string before and after the date like this:
 `Hello d2 your date is 24/11/2013 thank you`.
 I tried this:

```
preg_match('(\d{2})(/)(\d{2})(/)(\d{4})$',  $my_date_s, $matches);
```

but this shows error

Comment: How about `'#(\d{2})(/)(\d{2})(/)(\d{4})$#'`

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match('~^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$~', $my_date_s, $matches);`

main thing is that you didn't include delimiters. I added a start of string anchor since  you had an end of string one.. but it's hard to know if the regex will suit you without seeing your content.. this pattern assumes the *only* thing in the string is your date.

So if it's a date inside a string with other stuff in it, do this:

`preg_match('~\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b~', $my_date_s, $matches);`

Also FYI, this is just a simple verification.. it validates format but not if it's a real date. If you want to validate it as a real date, you can [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) at the `/` and then use [checkdate](http://www.php.net/checkdate)

Answer (score 1):

It won't match anything because of not supplying beginning and ending delimiters in your expression. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

See [`PHP: Delimiters`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

```
preg_match('~\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b~',  $my_date_s, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Regular expression:

```
\b          the boundary between a word char (\w) 
            and something that is not a word char
\d{2}       digits (0-9) (2 times)
 /          '/'
\d{2}       digits (0-9) (2 times)
 /          '/'
\d{4}       digits (0-9) (4 times)
\b          the boundary between a word char (\w) 
            and something that is not a word char
```